# How to add single quotes in laravel .env

Tags: php, laravel, variables, environment-variables, environment

I want to add a single quote in the .env file but nothing of the following seems to be working:

```
ALL_VIDEOS=App\Models\Video::where(\'video_type\', \'=\', \'Free\')->get();

ALL_VIDEOS=App\Models\Video::where(''video_type'', ''='', ''Free'')->get();
```

Comment: try putting everything inside double quotes `ALL_VIDEOS="App\Models\Video::where('video_type', '=', 'Free')->get();"`.  BTW: that looks strange into the .env file.

Comment: @porloscerrosΨ Still doesn't work, Yeah but I wanted a way to show a variable through all the views without getting back to the controller

Comment: I'm not sure having a Laravel Eloquent query in an .env file will work. You might be better off putting that in the Video model as a static function.

Comment: @aynber Thank you for the tip, what you suggested helped

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ALL_VIDEOS=App\Models\Video::where('""video_type""', '""=""', '""Free""')->get();
```